# How do sites know if you're connecting through a VPN?

Tags: vpn

I used privateinternetaccess and sometimes encounter sites that don't load if you connect over VPN. One example is Southwest Airlines (southwest.com). Other sites like Netflix won't play the video if you're connecting to a region different than your own.

How do sites like Southwest realize I'm connecting through a VPN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some sites will be explicitly blacklisting known VPN IP addresses, as Matthew says. Since many dodgy people will attempt to do nasty things through the anonymity of a VPN, many companies simply choose to block them and aren't bothered by 'legitimate' VPN users being inconvenienced.

Others may do this with an algorithm - if many users access a site via the same VPN, that site will see an unusually high number of visits from the same IP address, which will look like suspicious network activity. This will be doubly true for sites with user accounts - seeing many different users all logging in from the same IP address will also look suspicious. Those IP addresses then end up getting blocked. A few sites may choose to whitelist reputable VPNs, but most probably won't bother.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. No idea why this question was downvoted, but appreciate the thorough answer!

Comment: I guess it's downvoted because it's not really a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

---

Through IP.  I've heard of a few businesses that have started to blacklist VPN nodes. A proxy and/or bouncing off another VPN should clarify & potentially solve your issue.